What causes the web server return different HTTP codes?
Reviewing Apache's access_ssl_log I've come across certain scanbots activity that to my surprise causes strange server responses
I.e.
47.236.232.202 - - [29/Nov/2024:08:29:50 +0100] "GET /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1672 "-" "Custom-AsyncHttpClient"

When I run the same endpoint from curl or a web browser I reliable get a 404 because this url is not supported by our PHP application.
109.245.200.62 - - [29/Nov/2024:16:58:51 +0100] "GET /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 8298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"

Nonetheless for some reason when a bot issues the same request, they receive a 200, which makes be nervous as they may be able to somehow circumvent our application router and even run the PHP files remotely.
How do I debug this situation and identify the reason why the web server returns a success code to the bot?
FWIW my phpunit's version is 11.2.5 so I'd think that it should not be prone to this particular vulnerability.

you could maybe try to log exactly what this bot sends in its request - exact URL, all headers, any body, and compare to what you're sending. We can see that the user-agent string is different, so that could be a factor. But why your webserver responds differently to that is more of a puzzle. You'd need to understand if it's Apache giving that response directly, or your application routing. And we can't see any settings, or how that's implemented etc. More info needed before we can help, really.

You can't block CURL requests since everything can be "faked", Headers, Body... I guess the Bot sends the correct Header to fake a true HTTP request.

ADyson Actually it's a Plesk-managed server and I don't have the permission to modify the log format

I am very surprised why you allow access to the vendor directory from outside.

@MarkusZeller Could you elaborate on that? I've inherited this project from somebody else and I don't see that I allow anything like that enywhere

As you can see the GET request is /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php. The vendor directory contains composer libraries which ONLY the application should be able to see and to call. That's the reason why a "httpdocs" is the default directory for website and everything in there may be called by any browser without a problem. If I know internals about your structure and could call code directly I could go for remote code execution and harm all your server. Just scratching the surface, but I think you get the point.

@MarkusZeller We have an .htaccess file that redirects every request to a single PHP router that refuses anything other than one of the allowed endpoints. So I'm not sure what you mean by "everything in there may be called by any browser without a problem"

Take yourself some time and think over why a Firefox browser can access files from vendor directory. If you really think a .htaccess file protects you, good luck.
